# Code first tables not created after deploying to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, azure-web-app-service, entity-framework-migrations

I have this site in MVC + EF code first. It's running perfect on Azure VM and local.

Recently I want to switch to Azure Web App so I deployed the site to my Web App service in VS2013. Everything looked good, Execute Code First Migrations was checked, and no error.

However when I looked into database, only about 10 out of 20 tables are created. I looked further into __MigrationHistory table and found only 34(including initial migration) out of 69 migrations changes are there. That is the code first didn't run through. I tried many times and it looks like it's stuck there. It's so frustrating. Could anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Try generating an idempotent script on your DEV side that you can use to debug the issue: Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase  This will include each migration wrapped by an If statement.

Comment: Make sure the context key is the same for all the inserted __MigrationHistory records in the script.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve! I found there is one constraint I need to manually drop and add after running MigrationHistory32. Odd is Azure didn't return any error or warning message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though Azure and VS2013 didn't return any error or warning message. By using Steve's method, I found there is one constraint I need to manually drop and add after running MigrationHistory32.